# When are the convergent sequences the eventually constant ones?

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

Throughout this question $X$ will be an uncountable set. It is not too difficult to see that if $X$ is equipped with the co-countable topology then the convergent sequences are precisely those which are eventually constant. Is the co-countable topology the coarsest topology with this property?

So far I have only been able to show that if $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is such that all convergent sequences are eventually constant then $\mathcal{T}_{cof} \subseteq \mathcal{T}$ where $\mathcal{T}_{cof}$ is the co-finite topology on $X$. Indeed if $x,y$ are distinct points which are not separated then wlog $x$ is in every neighbourhood of $y$ so $(x,y,x,y, \dots)$ converges to $y$ so $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is $T_1$ and therefore singletons and hence all finite sets are closed.

Comment: One sometimes defines UL as a separation axiom of sorts: every convergent sequence has a unique limit. It’s implied by $T_2$ and your argument is used to see UL implies $T_1$. FYI.

Comment: A topology contains the cocountable topology iff all countable sets are closed and discrete. So no such space can be even countably compact.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  For example, the Stone-Cech compactification $\beta \mathbb N$ of the natural numbers contains no nontrivial convergent sequences, and not all cocountable sets are open.